# Firefox not reading the paramter passed to javascript location method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `location.assign(url)` method in all browser except firefox URL redirection is happening correctly.

In Firefox its read the URL and remove the parameter attached to the URL.

```
url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?at=87657741&language=en"
```

which is passed to `location.assign(url)` or `location = url` or `window.location.href= url..`

But in Firefox converts the entire URL to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` and refreshes the page.

This link is generated on clicking dropdown item.

What I am doing wrong over here.

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using? On which platform? Might be a bug, if the same code works on Chrome, IE etc, but not in FF. If you just do something like location.assign('http://google.com/?q=puppies') what happens in various browsers? _Later edit_: tried that and it worked on my Firefox.

Comment: Firefox - 50.1 Version, Mac OS

Comment: I have the same version, on a Mac. Do you see the issue with the simple test-case? For me it managed to load Google, and set the query string to puppies (though no search was performed - i guess it's more complicated nowadays to do it). I observed the same behaviour in Chrome.

Comment: FF 51.0.1: `location.assign('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?at=87657741&language=en')` works fine

Comment: It works on local but not on the domain.